# log4j2 doesn't generate log when using URLClassLoader to dynamic load another jar

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j2 to create running log in my system.
And here is the relationship between modules.
[image]

log4j2 has been put into common.jar. The miner.jar is a standalone executable program, also it will generate log throw common.jar(log4j2). 
Also miner.jar will dynamic load data.jar to do some jobs with URLClassLoader, the data.jar has a separate folder different with miner.jar. data.jar also contains common.jar in it's folder. data.jar will be loaded in P.war.
Now when I start miner.jar, it can be output log correctly in log file(configuration in log4j2.xml), but no logs be output in data.jar.

Can someone point the problem in this architecture?